# Rooting ASUS MeMO Pad (Nougat 7.1.2)

Tags: rooting, 7.1-nougat

I'm a freshman that just started working as a research assistant for my school's computer science department. My advisor is having me root some Asus tablets and install Lineage OS 14.1, and I have been having some issues. I have tried a lot of different softwares such as Framaroot, Kingoroot, One-Click-Root, and basically anything else I could find, and everything either wasn't compatible/wouldn't work or cost like $30. Thanks in advance if anyone has any advice!!

Comment: Whats the model number of the memo pad?

Comment: I remember the number K013 but not sure if that was the model number or something else. I don't have it with me currently, but I work in like an hour so I will check then!!

Comment: Sorry for the wait there but it is K013!

Comment: Look for an unofficial TWRP custom recovery for the Asus  k013 on like XDA flash it through the bootloader. Next, look for the latest version of Magisk systemless root and flash it through TWRP.